# Pandas JSON_normalize (nested json) - int object error

Tags: python, json, pandas

i have tried the below code to normalize JSON, but getting error - " AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'values'"

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import http.client
import json

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.buyucoin.com")
payload = ''
headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

conn.request("GET", "/ticker/v1.0/liveData?symbol=USDT-INR", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data1 = res.read()

print(data1.decode("utf-8"))
df = pd.json_normalize(data1)
```

It works fine when i use df=pd.read_json(data1)

Below is JSON Data:

'''

```
{"status":"success","sub_status":null,"data":[{"bid":"76.5","ask":"78.9","sprd":"3.041","tVolAsk":"123783.0199","tVolBid":"265729.9668","h24":"99.92","l24":"76.5","v24":"33942.2532","tp24":"2603097.335376","LTRate":"76.5","LTVol":"3178.9228","LBRate":"76.5","LBVol":"3178.9228","LSRate":"76.5","LSVol":"3178.9228","c24":"-2.5","c24p":"-3.16","marketName":"INR-USDT","currToName":"TETHER"}]}
```

'''

Please advise a solution to avoid that int error.

thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the **full text** of the traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the help of `pd.json_normalize(...)`, it says

```
Parameters
----------
data : dict or list of dicts
    Unserialized JSON objects.
```

It means that you have to parse it first. Since your `data1['data']` is a list of jsons, you need to specify `data` as a key and two upper level fields as metadata fields.

```
>>> import json
>>> df = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(data1), 'data', ['status', 'sub_status'])
>>> df
    bid   ask   sprd      tVolAsk      tVolBid    h24   l24         v24            tp24 LTRate LTVol LBRate LBVol LSRate LSVol    c24   c24p marketName currToName   status sub_status
0  76.5  78.9  3.041  123783.0199  263083.9668  99.92  76.5  36584.2532  2805200.335376   76.5  2646   76.5  2646   76.5  2646  -0.53  -0.68   INR-USDT     TETHER  success       None
```

Comment: if Jason data is like below:

{"status":"success","sub_status":null,"data":{"SELL":[{"price":"1000000","qty":"0.0009","total":"900"},{"price":"255","qty":"0.45","total":"114.75"},{"price":"78.9","qty":"508.0704","total":"40086.75456"}],"BUY":[{"price":"76","qty":"6","total":"456"},{"price":"40","qty":"2.323","total":"92.92"},{"price":"9","qty":"43.2222","total":"388.9998"}]}}

then 
df = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(data1), 'data', ['status', 'sub_status']) is not giving desired results. please advise

Comment: Can you post in a new question?